# sphinx emit (discard) search fields

Tags: sphinx

Suppose we have some search params like (author, genre, cost) and we have to get `N=15` rows

Query : `select ... where author=a and genre=b and cost=b LIMIT N`

We have to get `N` rows, but we found only 2 rows. Then we have to emit param cost.

Query : `select ... where author=a and genre=b LIMIT N`

now we have `10 < N` rows, so we have to emit author

Query : `select ... where author=a LIMIT N` and so on..

How to make it in right way (i think to make multi queries is expensive,

to make query like: `select if (author=a and genre=b and cost=c, 1, 0) as f, if (author=a and genre=b, 1, 0) as s, ... order by f desc, s desc, ...`
is expensive too because table has more 500 000 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably make it a bit more efficient, with

```
select ...,author=a + genre=b + cost=c as f from order by d desc
```

(if want to maintain priority can do `(author=a * 4) + ...` etc)

But in general, you have no MATCH() so the query will ALWAYS be a full-table scan. It will have to inspect and potentially sort EVERY row in the table.

There is no way to make it truly efficient. (Other than pre-computing values and storing them in the index - could even precompute values in fields to take advantage of the full-text index)